# Uniqueness of Sets: Is there one number one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To make the question exact, assume we are working with von Neumann ordinals in ZFC. Consider the statement $1=1$. Does each symbol "$1$" reference literally the same set $\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace$; or, by writing the numeral "$1$" twice, have I summoned two identical copies of $\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace$ into existence? Does it even make sense to talk about "copies" of a set?

I know this type of issue is probably not relevant to the way mathematicians actually practice their craft and that "don't worry about it" is a sufficient answer for most (all?) situations; but I still desire an answer of some sort.

Comment: $\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace=\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace$ since you have two sets with the same elements, namely $\emptyset$, so they are the same set.

Comment: You have two *instances* of a single term; in any reasonable interpretation of the word "reference," this doesn't involve multiple referents. A (slightly) more interesting example would be something like "$1+1=2$;" there we have two instances of the term $1$ which (of course) each reference the same object, a "larger" term $1+1$ which references a different object, and a different term term $2$ which references the same object as $1+1$. (Incidentally, this idea of terms referencing objects is really just ... basic model theory, and the idea of valuations and assignments!)

Comment: This isn’t computer science, where we could do `x = new EmptySet(); y = new EmptySet();` and then distinguish `x` and `y` using their memory addresses. In math, equal things are totally indistinguishable.

Comment: Revisiting this much later, the comment by @MarkSaving answered the question I was trying to ask. Does it make sense to talk about multiple copies of the same object within the context of mathematics? It seems the answer is no.